# Display iOS Compass Within iOS Native Web App Page

Tags: ios, web, native, compass-geolocation

I am trying to figure out how to display an iOS Compass directly onto a page I created from within my iOS Native Web App. I don't want to tap on an area and it bring me to the compass application.

Essentially, I am working on a project where the accelerometer can be tested with the rotation of the device by using the iOS compass directly on my page without having to go directly into the compass application.

(It's kind of hard to explain. My apologies for that.)

Img Ex.

http://i442.photobucket.com/albums/qq145/inmyeyesurpsycho/AVF%20Project/ScreenShot2013-04-14at65356PM_zpsa0ab43e8.png

(The Password Is: compass)

If someone has any advice on what I can do to make this happen, I would really appreciate it.

P.s.

It has to work as an iOS Native Feature.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell there's no way to access the Accelerometer through a safari web app. So, you'll need to use something like google GPS to figure out that info.

Comment: It's actually a native application on my iPad 4 that I built. I was trying to add something in that Acc. Test box that would show a live compass for accelerometer testing as shown in the image link I provided.